# Flex layout: show first element when two child elements are in the same row

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have this simple template:

HTML:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left inner">The quick brown fox</div>
  <div class="right inner">jumps over the lazy dog</div>
</div>
```

The displayed result looks like `The quick b... jumps over th...`

How could I make it try to fully display the first element before putting in the second one? If there's not enough space for the first part, simply drop the second one.

It should look something like `The quick brown fo...`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the .left that it shouldn't shrink. You can accomplish this by setting flex-shrink: 0;

```
.left {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abx03fpx/

Comment: Thanks! What if the `.outer` element is only 100px wide? I'd still like to have ellipsis when even the first element doesn't fit. Something like `the quic...`

Comment: Sure, just give .inner a max-width of 100%